# Inherited JPanel locking up the program

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jpanel

While writing a Java program, I found myself using three identical methods in several JPanels so I thought, why not spare myself some typing and extend JPanel into an abstract class containing only these methods, then extend the abstract class into my panels?

Yeah, the program does precisely nothing now. It doesn't even display a window and according to NetBeans, it's running only two threads whereas it should normally be running over a dozen.

Here's the abstract class:

```
import ControlClasses.MainWindow;
import ControlClasses.MethodLibrary;
import java.awt.Component;

public abstract class CustomPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    protected MainWindow parent;
    protected MethodLibrary library;

/**
 * Sets the owner of this panel for the purpose of method calls.
 * @param parentFrame The JFrame this panel is located on.
 */
public void setParent(MainWindow parentFrame){
    this.parent = parentFrame;
}

/**
 * If the panel is on a JLayeredField, this can be used to disable all components
 * in order to prevent user input from reaching this panel instead of the intended one.
 * @param mode The state to set all controls to.
 */
public void changeFunctionality(boolean mode){
    for(Component comp : this.getComponents()){
        comp.setEnabled(mode);
        comp.setVisible(mode);
    }
}

/**
 * Adds the method library to the class.
 * @param library The library's handle.
 */
public void addLibrary(MethodLibrary library){
    this.library = library;
}
}
```

Did I miss out something here?

Comment: I would suggest that your problems are else where...

Comment: maybe not the problem, but to avoid visual confusion as well as make your compiler more strict (and point out possible problems) make sure to use the `@Override` annotation when extending classes.

Comment: Did I miss out something here? - yes an  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), short, runnable, compilable and for the real answer I missing  there description about expected goal

Comment: @mKorbel what? i don't think one can post a short, runnable, and compilable example if the problem is the code can't run and is not compilable.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? I'm pretty sure that NetBeans provides one?

Comment: @ the OP - Try posting some more code for us to see, including where this class is being instantiated, etc. It may provide clues as-to where the problem lies.

Comment: @SnakeDoc If the OP says the application hangs, then yes he should be able to post a short piece of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SnakeDoc  I see no indication in the question that is a compilation problem.  Did you see something I missed? In fact *"it's running only two threads"* strongly suggests a *run-time problem.*  2nd the call for an MCVE.

Comment: I found the problem; it's in an entirely unrelated panel where I implemented a KeyListener. I, uh... I suppose I shouldn't have told the listener to wait() in order to keep it from firing actions before it's supposed to, have I?

Comment: @ the OP - I'd post your solution as an "answer" below and mark it as the correct one so that other can learn too. Also, I'd post some more code to give context to the problem as well as it's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as it turns out, was in an entirely unrelated panel.

What happened is that I wrote another panel with a KeyListener and a MouseMotionListener but as the entire setup is on a LayeredPane, I had prior problems with the wrong panel getting the mouse input. Therefore, I tried to disable the listeners with the following:

```
KeyListener kListener = new KeyListener(){ events for the listener, not important here };
MouseMotionListener mListener = new MouseMotionListener() { ditto };
synchronized (kListener){
    kListener.wait();
}
synchronized (mListener){
    mListener.wait();
}
```

The intention was to notify() a listener once it is needed and have it wait() again once unneeded. However, action listeners are NOT threads; when I told them to wait, the command was executed on the event dispatch thread which silently put the program into an unrecoverable infinite loop, with everyone waiting for the EDT which itself was waiting for a notify() that would never come - the classic example of a deadlock. The reason the program never even displayed a window was because the EDT was halted while the program was still initializing, halting it in the middle of the constructor of the program's main window and thus before there was a window to display.

Solution: when NetBeans warns you about trying to execute synchronize() on a non-final field, *listen to it*. There's a *reason* it's trying to get your attention. It was a stupid mistake but at least it was a harmless one.